# Calling methods on an MFC UI class in a separate thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc

I have two threads in my MFC application. One of them handles all Wnd stuff and the other some file management. Is it generally a good idea to call some methods on UI classes from other threads? Like for example to update some values the UI fields are showing to user. Or it is a bad practice and I have to send messages to the windows classes? If we try to use locks in UI threads, GUI will freeze frequently which is not really acceptable unless it is for a very trivial job. What is the best practice here? Should we solely use message passing mechanisms when dealing with UI?

There are also some methods on UI which don't involve data or variables. For example telling a window to maximize. Is it bad to call a public method in UI class in this case?

[EDIT]
I forgot to tell about my problem with sending messages. Your parameters a always two pointers and not easily customizable.

Comment: Best practice is probably to use SendMessage(). You can use custom messages or whatever your heart desires.

Comment: Yeah that is what I guessed (educated guess). So I did so in case of the feature I implemented. But there are cases still in code that are calling methods in window classes.

Comment: In my experience there's no way around defining structures/classes to carry the information needed and using pointers to that structures in SendMessage(). You need a pointer to the correct structure in each custom message handler and strict rules which part is responsible for freeing the memory needed for the structures.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, UI is supposed too be light and responsive. To accomplish that, all the heavy duty works should be handled by a separate thread, wherein it can communicate with the main mfc UI thread using `SendMessage()`.

Commands such as maximizing windows have fairly small overhead and can be accomplished in the UI thread itself. To simulate a long process, the UI can use an animated progress bar, for instance.

Decoupling UI from the program engine also will make your code more modular, reusable and the intent clearer.

Comment: Maximizing windows yes. But my question is if there are some sort of rules or best practice on calling methods of a UI class. Maximizing a windows was a bad example. Because t could be simply done by a message. A better is to call method in UI class to make it read some data from elsewhere. And that method has for example 4 different parameters. You could keep your code much clearer if you could do it this way instead of using send message and send thoses parameters as lParam and wParam.

Comment: Say if you have to populate a listctrl with sizeable data and you want the UI to be responsive, than it would be wise to fill the data aync from another thread. SendMessage() is just another means, you can also use sockets, osc, etc. Imagine to want to animate a dynamic audio bars on your control every 250ms by read data through osc; here you won't like spending every 250ms of UI thread for plotting, you need to tackle differently.

Comment: Now the question is in MFC is it an acceptable practice to use other means?

Comment: The UI thread and the worker thread has to communicate asynchronously. This can be achieved simply using SendMessage, where the messages will be pushed to message queue. Alternately, you can setup a timer in your mfc control to check the status of the atomic variables shared across threads very safely. But updating the MFC controls from others thread should be avoided.